# How to solve the cookie storage problem in Chrome version 80+?

Tags: angular, cookies, google-chrome-app

I am using Angular 7.2.7 in the front-end with Python in the back-end.
I am also using **ngx-cookie-service** to set and get the cookie. My both front-end and back-end domain are in https.

But the Chrome browser blocks to set the token in the cookie after successful login. How can I solve this problem?

to set the cookie, I have used `this.cookieService.set('token', 'something')` and to get the cookie I have used `this.cookieService.get('token')`.

The warning I get in the console is:

> A cookie associated with a resource at  was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

The token is not passed through HTTP headers.

Is there any way in Angular so that I can get rid of the blockage that chrome is causing?

Comment: What version of this package are you using? It looks like the issue was fixed with ```3.0.2``` https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/pull/89

Comment: The ngx-cookie-service version that I am using is ^2.2.0

Comment: Try to update the package, see if it fixes it.

Comment: This version of ngx-cookie-service does not work with Angular 7.2.7

Comment: I see. It seems that there is a method to pass in arguments for both the samesite and secure attributes:
```set( name: string, value: string, expires?: number | Date, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite?: 'Lax' | 'Strict' | 'None' ): void;```
Where secure would be set to ```true``` and sameSite to ```None```. Have you tried this? So your call would look like:
```this.cookieService.set("token","something", undefined, undefined, undefined, true, 'None');```